# WooCommerce - how can i find the id of my term?

Tags: php, woocommerce, attributes, hook-woocommerce, taxonomy-terms

I just want to show the description of the attribute's term that's on my WooCommerce website.

I.E. the 172 in this hard code

```
    $product_attributes['condition'] = [
        'label' => __('Condition', 'text-domain'),
        'value' => __($product->get_attribute('condition').'<p>'. term_description(172) .'</p>', 'text-domain'),
    ];
```

I got the term by the get_attribute but i can't find his ID. term_description works fine but i have to find the ID to be flexible.

Do you have any solutions for me?

Thank you !

I've tried get_terms but no result. Same with ->description

Answer (score 0):

```
    // You can get local product attributes like the one below, but there is no ID (0) for local product attributes.
    $wc_local_product_attribute_values = $product->get_attribute('condition');
    
    // You can get global product attributes like below.
    $wc_global_product_attribute_values = $product->get_attribute('pa_condition');
    
    $wc_product_attribute = $product->get_attributes();
    // Get the ID of the attribute
    $attr_id = $wc_product_attribute['pa_condition']->get_id();
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the last line doesn't work for me. Any idea?

Comment: $wc_product_attribute['pa_condition'] return NULL (even with condition instead of pa_condition)

Comment: Please verify if the slug of that attribute is `condition` to use it as `$wc_product_attribute['pa_condition']`

Comment: Solve it like that :

$attributes = $product->get_attributes();
$id_condition = $attributes['pa_condition']['options'][0];